# What are the major flaws of the "caloric" theory of heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, history

I was reading about the history of thermodynamics and came across Lavoisier's idea of heat. He proposed that heat was a fluid. I am curious to know what are the major drawbacks of this theory. I know that if heat is fluid then it must have mass and this means that if a body is heated then its mass must increase. However, this is not the case. Are there any other major contentions that can be added to this list?

Thank You.

Comment: I don't think this is a question about physics. At best it's history of physics and would be best asked on the [history of science SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think that it is useful to have this explanation on tap as physics in the sense that it should be possible to succinctly convince students that a fluid model of heat isn't tenable. There certainly is a good hsm question here, but we don't need to be limited to the historical development in showing students the flaws in the notion.

Answer (score 3):

The caloric theory turns on there being a conserved quantity whose presence determines the temperature of an object and which can be transferred. So lets look at some ways to break the model.

- Do Joule's mechanical equivalent of heat experiment. Temperature in the stirred liquid increases without a source of caloric present.
- Do any kind of adiabatic expansion process with a gas system to generate work. Here temperature drops without there being a sink for caloric present.
- Transfer heat by radiative means across a vacuum. This one isn't a slam dunk, but if we are conceiving of caloric as a fluid, then how does it cross the gap?

Hanging onto caloric as a model in the face of those concerns would require some unnatural gyrations, while replacing it with a notion of internal energy is natural.